# How to download files using OFF (Owner Free File System) P2P?

Tags: p2p

I am testing P2P apps. I have downloaded OFF (Owner free Filesystem) P2P from the below link:

```
http://sourceforge.net/projects/offsystem/files/OFF%20System/
```

But I am unable to download any files using this client. I am not getting error messages even. I have referred following link also.

```
REF:

http://www.ghacks.net/2009/04/10/p2p-the-owner-free-file-system/
```

Please suggest some ideas if any of you used this OFF system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I recall, the program ships with a list of bootstrap nodes. Chances are as active development ceased (at least as far as I am aware) many years ago that none of the bootstrap nodes are online.

I doubt that you will be able to get the network to function as there are unlikely to be any other nodes still running.

If you were to set-up a cluster of VM's running the software, it should be possible to set a bootstrap node in the config somewhere, once it has a connection, it will retrieve a list of other nodes that it can connect to.